# How to control a device connected to USB in the client of ASP.NET Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have card reader device and it is connected to the computer by USB, I have sdk dll writted in .NET to use the device. and I have developped a web application, and I need to add the feature of using this card reader in one of the pages, like to click a button and the card number will be pasted in a text box.

My question is, how can I use this device connected to a client but not connected to the server, and using the same web application?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to create a browser plugin to access non-storage devices from a web site. Consider a Java applet or Silverlight.

Comment: I guess it is nice idea, I've tried to go through wrapping the .NET DLL in OCX and call this OCX in the client, but I couldn't succedd. Can you guide me in steps how to Create this JApplet and how to create .NET object from JApplet?

Comment: Like I said, you need to use Silverlight. It is like Java applets for .NET. http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/ Adobe Air is another idea.